# Multiplication between 2 text fields (Android App)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Alright so I am fairly new to android app development. I guess you could also say coding in general. I am only familiar with Visual Basic and some HTML/CSS. I am using eclipse and developing in android 1.5

```
EditText costofmeal, tippercent;
TextView tiptotal;
Button calctipbtn;
BigDecimal costNum, percentNum;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    calctipbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calctipbtn);

    costofmeal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CostofMeal); 
    tippercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PercentTipText);

    tiptotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiptotal);

    calctipbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            costNum = new BigDecimal(costofmeal.getText().toString());
            percentNum = new BigDecimal(tippercent.getText().toString());
            tiptotal.setText(costofmeal.multiply(tippercent).toString());



        }
    });









}
```

What I want to do is to have tiptotal represent costofmeal * tippercent after calctipbtn is pushed. I have looked at tutorials and other things I just cant seem to get it to work the only error I am getting right now is

The Method muliply(EditText) is undefined for the type EditText

any help sorry if this has been asked before I looked around and couldn't find something that I understood maybe it had been asked before but I only saw examples that dealt with when they declared and integer and put the variables in. Just not sure how to do it in this case.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just use the wrong variables :

```
tiptotal.setText(costNum.multiply(percentNum).toString());
```

costNum and percentNum are the are Number while costofmeal and tippercent are texts, so you can't multiply them.

Comment: Sorry didn't mark it until now my fault :) its done thanks again